# How can I get all results containing elasticsearch-dsl query keyword?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

When I query my PostDocument it returns the results that only contain full words from the query. For example if there were 4 posts:

```
1. "Post 1"
2. "Post 2"
3. "Posts 3"
4. "Po 4"
```

and I query it with: `posts = PostDocument.search().query('match', body="Post")` it will return items 1 and 2, if `body="Po"` it will return only item 4. How can I write the query so it returns all the results that contain the keyword? For example if I did this `body="Po"` I would get all 4 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use the [edge_ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) first breaks text down into
> words whenever it encounters one of a list of specified characters,
> then it emits N-grams of each word where the start of the N-gram is
> anchored to the beginning of the word.

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 10,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "max_ngram_diff": 50
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "body": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "body": "Post 1"
}
{
  "body": "Post 2"
}
{
  "body": "Posts 3"
}
{
  "body": "Po 4"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "body": "Po"
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "64684245",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 0.1424427,
        "_source": {
          "body": "Po 4"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "64684245",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.10158265,
        "_source": {
          "body": "Post 1"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "64684245",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.10158265,
        "_source": {
          "body": "Post 2"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "64684245",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.088840574,
        "_source": {
          "body": "Posts 3"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: And how would I write the query in the pythonic way?

Comment: @SLDem sorry I am not aware of python code :( But in elasticsearch in JSON format, it can be achieved by using edge_ngrams. Please don't forget to upvote my answer, if it helped you :)

Comment: @SLDem if you are able to achieve using python also, then please accept my answer as well :)

Comment: np mate, yes I have :)